# How to modify a gem files in rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3 with bundler, I installed a gem using bundler, now I need to modify the flow of the gem slightly by modifying the controller of the gem, how am I supposed to do so, i'm sure there is a command to install the files locally so I can modify it, I tried to override the controller by creating another controller with the same name but sounds not working .

Comment: Do you just want to add or modify a method or do you want to do a more fundamental change?

Comment: I installed a gem called contact-us , and I need to change the behavior of the controller there, if I can achieve this in anyway i would be happy by modifying the method or by anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to make a controller, inherit from the gem controller and override the method behavior as you see fit

```
class MyController < ContactUs::ContactsController
  def create
    # my code that changes the behavior
  end
end
```

And then you may have to tell your routes to go to your controller

```
resources :contacts,
  :controller => 'my_controller'
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the help, it is exactly what i'm looking for, I guess the route supposed to be resources :contacts,:controller => 'my' in case u named the file my_controller

Answer (score 9):

Fork it on github, make the changes and point your gemfile to the forked repo like so:

```
gem "contact-us", :git => "git://github.com/eqbal/contact-us.git"
```